# where is the real time copy of the index.html that ember-cli serves?

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js, ember-cli, serve

How do I get to the latest index.html file that will be served by ember-cli from its tmp folders?

I am doing some post processing on the final copies of the generated index.html and I am unable to find docs or references to how I can pick this path up on node side of things right before I serve the html when a GET request is being honored.

Basically, I have a use case to manipulate the index.html, add some tags(in real time). Right now I use `dist/index.html`, but that seems to just be a temporary copy.

Comment: It may be possible to alter build process in `ember-cli-build.js`. The tree there should contain `index.html` file that is going to be transfered into tmp and later dist folders.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`ember-index` addon](https://github.com/ramybenaroya/ember-index) which allows you to inject content into `index.html`. From their [multiple injection example](https://github.com/ramybenaroya/ember-index/wiki/Multiple-Injection-Example) you'll want something like:

**ember-cli-build.js**

```
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    'ember-index': {
      content: [{
        key: 'content',
        file: 'example.txt',
        includeInOutput: true,
        includeInIndexHtml: true
      }]
    }
  });

  return app.toTree();
};
```

**app/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     {{content-for 'ember-index-content'}}
     ...
  </head>
  <body>
     ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Which will inject the content from `example.txt` into the head of `index.html`.